# Cut, paste and shift a range one row up when delete button "btnS2" is clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I've made a macro that adds data to a list, a sub to create a button next to this list data that when clicked allows you to remove it, and another sub `btnS2()` that actually removes the data. I've got everything working except if someone deletes data from the middle of the list I need this void to be filled by the data below it or "shifted up". I've even nearly completed this but I cant seem to get it pasting correctly so it's probably a very simple problem. Please help.

```
Sub btnS2()
Dim b As Object
Dim r As Long, c As Long, firstrow As Long
Dim cell As Range

With Worksheets("Skill Summary")
    Set b = .Buttons(Application.Caller)  'references button
    With b.TopLeftCell                  'returns row and col of button pushed
        r = .row
        c = .Column - 1
    End With

    Set cell = .Cells(r, c)
    cell.ClearContents
    Call buttonGenerator_skillSummary
    Call shiftup(cell)

End With
End Sub
```

So this is my sub to select a range, cut it and paste it one row above. I've manager to get everything working except the paste on the second last line `Worksheets("Skill Summary").selection.Offset(-1, 0).Paste`

```
Sub shiftup(cell As Range)
Dim sel As Range
Dim firstrow As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

firstrow = cell.row + 1
lastrow = 1000

Set sel = Range("B" & firstrow & ":" & "B" & lastrow)
With sel
    .Select
    .Cut
End With
Worksheets("Skill Summary").selection.Offset(-1, 0).Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Range.Cut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-cut-method-excel) with the optional Destination argument.

```
Sub shiftup(cell As Range)

    Dim firstrow As Long, lastrow As Long

    firstrow = cell.row + 1
    lastrow = 1000

    with cell.parent.Range("B" & firstrow & ":B" & lastrow)
        .cut destination:=.offset(-1, 0)
    end with

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I used Range.copy instead as cut was dereferencing some corresponding cell formulae.

Comment: Glad to hear you got sorted out.